# How can I post multiple option's values from a select list to a MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, multi-select

I have a select list like the one below, and I need to post every option's value from the select list to the controller.  Is it possible to get these values somehow?

**Select List**

```
<select size="10" id="SelectedSortOrderOptions" name="SelectedSortOrderOptions">
    <option value="Parcel Number">Parcel Number</option>
    <option value="Receipt Number">Receipt Number</option>
    <option value="Municipality">Municipality</option>
</select>
```

Could I do something similar to this in my controller?

```
public IActionResult Submit(List<string> SelectedSortOrderOptions)
{
   ...
}
```

I need to get a new list of strings containing the values `Parcel Number`, `Receipt Number`, and `Municipality`.

Answer (score 5):

> Could I do something similar to this in my controller?

Yes, you could do that. If you want to define a select list with multiple options, in the view, you need to add `multiple` attribute to the `<select>` tag:

```
<form method="post" action="/home/submit">
    <select name="SelectedSortOrderOptions" multiple>
        <option value="Parcel Number">Parcel Number</option>
        <option value="Receipt Number">Receipt Number</option>
        <option value="Municipality">Municipality</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Submit(List<string> SelectedSortOrderOptions)
{
    return View();
}
```

You can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on Windows (or <kbd>command</kbd> key on Mac) while selecting for multiple options.

[image: 1]

Comment: I don't need the user to select items from the list, I just need to get the entire list and send it to the controller.  The list is populated by jquery from options that get moved to this select from another.

Comment: @sjohn285 You can use the same way to do that. But before submitting, you need to add `selected` attribute to all of the `<option>` items: `<option value="Parcel Number" selected>Parcel Number</option>`

Comment: @sjohn285 It can be done by jquery: `$("#SelectedSortOrderOptions option").prop('selected', true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery` to get all options and pass them to controller by `ajax`:

```
<script>
        $('#SelectedSortOrderOptions').change(function (e) {
            var optionsVal =[];
            $("#SelectedSortOrderOptions option").each(function () {
                optionsVal.push($(this).val());
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/submit',
                traditional: true,
                dataType: "json",
                data: { SelectedSortOrderOptions: optionsVal },
                success: function () {

                },
            });
        });
    </script>
```